# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range' what(): basic_string

Tags: c++

```
string word;
int l,eFound,xFound;
l = word.size();
cout <<"Enter a word: ";
cin >> word;

for (l>0 ; word.at(l)!='x' || word.at(l)!='e'; l--)
    if (word.at(l) == 'e'){
        eFound = true;
    }
    else if (word.at(l) == 'x'){
        xFound = true;
    }

if (eFound == true && xFound == true){
    cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'e'"<<"\n";
    cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'x'";
}
if (eFound == true && xFound != true){
    cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'e'";
}
if (xFound == true && eFound != true){
    cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'x'";
}
```

I'm not sure what is going on I'm trying to use a for loop to detect either e or x in a input of some word. I've clicked on other pages with the same error but they have different codes and I don't really understand what is explained. So what is causing this error? I'm 2 weeks into my first programming class, sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: That question is off-topic because it lacks a [mcve]. Extracting one, you would probably have found the mistake yourself. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: There are multiple issues with the above code. `l=word.size();` (should be `word.size()-1`) should be done after `cin`. The loop doesn't terminate unless 'x' or 'e' is found. So, the condition `l>0` should be added as terminating condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that indexing of `std::string` starts from zero. Not from 1. So, `word.at(l)` will crash if `l = word.size();`.

You should change the statement to: `l = word.size() - 1;`.

Also, Change your loop condition to `for (; l >= 0 ; l--)`

**Suggestion:**

Please go for library functions:

Like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word;
    cout <<"Enter a word: ";
    cin >> word;

    bool eFound = word.find('e') != string::npos;
    bool xFound = word.find('x') != string::npos;

    if (eFound) {
        cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'e'" << "\n";
    }

    if (xFound) {
        cout << "Your word, "<<word<<", contains the character 'x'" << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```